# How to adapt a "free space" partition for ubuntu 18.10?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I just got a windows 10 pc and i want to put on a partition ubuntu alongside with windows, i am a beginner and i'm facing some problems like, the usb stick with ubuntu's .iso doesn't get detected and ubuntu doesn't find windows but i'll go in the detalis later.

I'm following a guide(in my language) and i did the following steps:

- i unchecked the quick start option from the battery options
- i downloaded ubuntu 18.10 .iso and checked that MD5 checksum is correct
- i prepared a bootable usb with the "universal usb installer 9.8.7" program
- i created an empty partition of 400 gb

Now, i guess my pc has UEFI on it ( even though in booting menu i see the voice "BIOS options"?) since it's new, anyway i tried to disable secure boot, change every usb disk priority i could, the ubuntu usb didn't get detected at all. So i activated the "legacy" mode and it finally got detected, ubuntu opened up and i clicked the installation; but at this point the installation and the guide i'm following start to differ:

First there is a message saying that "/dev/sdb" is a disk with mounted partitions and asks if i want to unmount them before continuing (i chose no, i don't know what it does). Then in the screen where it should say it detected windows it says the pc has no operating systems and asks what to do; i go into the partitions menu, i click on the free space where i want to install ubuntu, then "install now":

[image]
After it an error pops up saying "no root file system is defined, please correct this from the partitioning menu"

Now, my question is this simple: what do i do to continue installation?
In "format" there are some options but i dont' want to blindy try things

Comment: Run gparted and create a partition on that free space. You didn't create an "empty partition"

Comment: @Pilot6 i ran it from ubuntu, but i didn't know what specifications i had to put in so i left the default ones. Now the free space is in type "ext4" but i still get the same error; what type do i have to use on gparted?

Comment: ext4 is OK, but on installation you should select mount point `/`. that you didn't do.